# Ge the current url or hostname in next ouside components

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js

I'm using firebase. I have a file config. In this file I have something like this:
`export const currentUrl = isEmulators ? "http://localhost:3000" : window.location.hostname`

But I'm getting undefined for window. I've been looking through other questions and they all recommend hooks. But my implementation is in a config file that is not inside any component.

Is there any way to retrieve current hostname outside of components using next js? Something like window.location.hostname

`export const currentUrl = isEmulators ? "http://localhost:3000" : window.location.hostname`